# DateTime::createFromFormat generating booleans?

Tags: php, datetime, date

Within a for loop, I'm using the following code to convert from one date format to another:

```
339: $newdate = date_create_from_format('j-M g:i A', $moneyline[$i][date]);
340: echo date_format($newdate, 'Y-m-d');
```

According to the `var_dump` of $moneyline[$i][date], my variable appears to be a string:
`string(15) "18-Jun 7:05 PM"`

But when I use the variable as an argument for the `$newdate` constructor, `$newdate` creates a boolean according to vardump:
`bool(false)`

That means when I try to execute line 340, I get the following error:

```
Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in /home/andrewmin/andrewmin.com/share/scraping/betting_scraping.php on line 340
```

However, if I change line 339 to:

```
339: $newdate = date_create_from_format('j-M g:i A', '18-Jun 7:05 PM');
```

it prints perfectly. Anyone have any ideas on why?

edit: sorry, it's not a foreach, it's a for:

```
for ($i = 2; $i < $array_length; $i++) {
```

Comment: Try to declare it to a date like, `date($moneyline[$i][date])`.

Comment: Can you show what the foreach looks like?  I only ask because I wonder if the `$i` counter is necessary.  It didn't make any difference for me, but I think the `date` index in `$moneyline[$i][date]` needs to be quoted, otherwise you get a warning.  But this didn't cause a problem for me.  `date_create_from_format` returns `FALSE` if it fails.

Comment: @thegrede - I tried doing this:

    $currentdate = date($moneyline[$i][date]);
    $newdate = date_create_from_format('j-M g:i A', $currentdate);
    echo date_format($newdate, 'Y-m-d');

Unfortunately, same error.

Comment: @drew010: my bad, it's a for, not a foreach: for ($i = 2; $i < $array_length; $i++)

Comment: Are you 100% sure that `$moneyline[$i][date]` is actually `18-Jun 7:05 PM` when the error occurs? You are walking through an array after all.

Comment: @Pekka printing $moneyline[$i][date] after creating the $newdate variable on 339 gives the following output: 18-Jun 7:05 PM

Comment: But it's a *loop*. Is that the only element in the loop?

Comment: @Pekka Is what the only element in the loop?

Comment: The `18-Jun 7:05 PM` value. Are you sure it's that that is causing the error? You are running through a loop with multiple elements. What other elements are there?

Comment: The other elements are being printed fine. I'm printing the elements to a table, and every value is printed fine except for the last column, which is where I'm trying to convert the date. The last column gives the same error every time, so I'm pretty sure it's the problem:

`Warning: date_format() expects parameter 1 to be DateTime, boolean given in /home/andrewmin/andrewmin.com/share/scraping/odds_scrape.php on line 346`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Surely when I test using this code:

```
$moneyline = array(
  13 => array(
    'date' => "18-Jun 7:05 PM"
  )
);
$i = 13;
$newdate = date_create_from_format('j-M g:i A', $moneyline[$i][date]);
echo date_format($newdate, 'Y-m-d');
```

I get this result:

```
**Notice:**  Use of undefined constant date - assumed 'date' in J:\www\test\datetime.php on line 89

2012-06-18
```

The notice can be gotten rid of by properly quoting the `'date'` array index.

My guess: your `$moneyline` array contains a string not conforming to the date format you provided (e.g. an empty string). In this case, `date_create_from_format` will fail and will return `false`.

If in doubt, please post a more complete copy of the code involved and an array the code fails on.

Comment: No, it's the correct format. I copied the output of var_dump ( `18-Jun 7:05 PM` ) and used it for the input, and it worked fine.

Comment: And yeah, I cleaned up the index arrays (good catch haha), but it didn't solve it.

Comment: I assume that your `$moneyline` array contains more than just 1 element, which is why I'm asking. Is it erroring out for every element, or just for this one? Again, please post a *complete* dump of the `$moneyline` array resulting in the error. This gives us a better handle to help you. Now we have to guess a lot because your problem description is incomplete.

Comment: Sorry... I realized that there was a random line break that var_dump apparently wasn't picking up. I removed it using preg_replace, and everything's working fine now.

Comment: Well I'm glad you sorted that out after all :)